# How not to lose special characters in Bibtex file?

Tags: bibtex, characters

My bibfile includes special characters. When I open the file with TexShop (4.70) which I used to create this file on my Mac, I see my special characters. When I open the file with Texmaker (5.1.3), I see the special characters followed by two boxes which are not present when I open the file in Texshop. How can I write special characters in a permanent way in a Bib-file and ensure that the file can be read and used by other people as well?

Example

This is what Texshop displays

```
@jurisdiction{Tadiccontempt,
 title         = {Prosecutor v. Dusko Tadi{\'c}‡‡ a/k/a "Dule"},
 subtitle      = {},
 titleaddon    = {ICTY AC Judgement on Allegations of Contempt against Prior Counsel, Milan Vujin (31 January 2000)},
 date          = {},
 number  = {IT-94-1-A-R77},
 pages         = {},
 keywords = {ICTY}, tabulate={ICTY},
}
```

This is what Texmakers displays:

```
@jurisdiction{Tadiccontempt,
 title         = {Prosecutor v. Dusko Tadi{\'c}**[here I see two boxes]** a/k/a "Dule"},
 subtitle      = {},
 titleaddon    = {ICTY AC Judgement on Allegations of Contempt against Prior Counsel, Milan Vujin (31 January 2000)},
 date          = {},
 number  = {IT-94-1-A-R77},
 pages         = {},
 keywords = {ICTY}, tabulate={ICTY},
}
```

The PDF does not print the ć in Tadić. How can I avoid these two boxes?

Comment: Thanks for editing! Just to be sure: the ‡‡ is not part of the original bibtex file. I would be grateful for any idea of how to use special characters in a way that allows me to send the file via email to other people who may use a different editor